# How to download root user owned files via scp or rsync as a sudo user?

Tags: ssh, rsync, scp, sshpass

How to download the file which requires `root` permission from a remote server (via `scp` or `rsync`) as a sudo-user (non-interactive way)?

**Note** that this sudo-user is not configured to not require the password for `sudo` commands.
And `sshpass` is installed on both local and remote systems.

And download command may look like this

```
sshpass -p {sudo-user-pass} scp {sudo-user}@{host}:/path/to/some/root/owned/file.tar.gz ./
```

This command gives a "permission denied" error as `file.tar.gz` is owned by the root.

In order to download this file, sudo-user should be switched to root `sudo -su`

So is there a way in `scp` or `rsync` where sudo-user can switch to root and download the root-owned files (non-interactively)?

Comment: 1. add your public ssh key to `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`, 2. check if `ssh root@ip` works. 3. scp should just work. No idea, why answers are super complex, but this rsync answer should just work https://serverfault.com/a/136554

Comment: I am usually thinking of ssh paths as lazily expanded paths on the remote system, which require to 1. have proper connection, 2. have permissions (via key) of the user.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer.  SCP doesn't allow it natively, but you can do a quick "ssh sudo cat" to achieve the same effect. It won't scale nicely for tons of files, but for 1 it may suffice.

[How can I scp a file that my user can't read but I can sudo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80740/how-can-i-scp-a-file-that-my-user-cant-read-but-i-can-sudo#answer-80762)